# Why is "start" script not running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I've very simple node&express app, work as expected but when I try to run the server from the script there is a problem.

If my script is "start", when I run the command it's just open my cmd.
If my script is any other word, I get this error:

> 'start1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file

How can I solve this problem? It's caused to problem with heroku too.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.2.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start1": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: are you entering `start` on the command line or `npm start` ?

Comment: You can simply do `npm run start1`

Answer (score 1):

To run a script you need to use "npm run" before the script name, as example:

```sh
$ npm run script1
```

npm-scripts docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts